# Rotating Image in Canvas, causing stretch of Image (getting wider and less high)

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rotation

I am running into a weird problem, while performing a simple rotation of an image.
While rotating an image around its center in a canvas, the image is stretched to double of its original width when rotating to 90° and is resizing to its normal width/height rotating to 180° then its stretching again to 270° and resizing back when rotating to 0° again. 
Also it seems like the Image is between those 90° steps a parallelogram and not a rectangle.

[image: "0"]
[image: "45"]
[image: "90"]
[image: "185"]

What I actually do is:

```
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
function drawRotatedImage(x, y, angle, width, height) {

    contextL.save();
    contextL.translate(x + width/2, y + height/2);
    contextL.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);

    var imgT = new Image();
    imgT.src = myPath;

    contextL.drawImage(imgT, -width/2, -height/2, width, height);

    contextL.restore();
}
```

ContextL is created like this:

```
canvasL = document.getElementById("canvasL");
```

`contextL = canvasL.getContext("2d");`

I really do not get, what is my fault here. I have read nearly all threads about rotating in canvas and all are doing exactly the same, but it is working. Only special may be, that I use `drawImage(image, x, y, width, height)` and not `drawImage(image, x, y)` but is this causing the trouble?

*With `drawImage(image, x, y)` same trouble is caused
*using `contextL.drawImage(imgT, -width/2, -height/2, width/2, height*2);` turns the effect around. Starting stretched and regular size at 90°, so it really it is getting the double of its width and half of its height when rotating to 90°.

*Width and Height are calculated as follows:

```
this.prepareIMG = function(){
    this.widthIMG = this.img.width * this.scale;
    this.heightIMG = this.img.height * this.scale;
};
```

This is the function I call every time right before I call `drawRotatedImage(...)`. `this.scale`is a value from `0.1`to `x` increasing/decreasing in steps of `0.1`.
 Also when I log the `width` and `height` during the rotation to the console, the value stays always the same!
I do not manipulate the `contextL`somewhere outside the function `drawRotatedImage(...)`!

This is the code which calls the rotate-function

```
    this.rotatePlus = function(){
    refreshCanvas();
    this.rotation += 5;
    this.prepareIMG();
    drawRotatedImage(contextL, this.transX, this.transY, this.rotation, this.widthIMG, this.heightIMG/2);
};
```

Finally `refreshCanvas()` is defined as follows

```
function refreshCanvas(){
contextL = canvasL.getContext("2d");
contextL.clearRect(0, 0, canvasL.width, canvasL.height);}
```

and my canvas is declared in HTML like this `<div id="divCanvasL"><canvas id="canvasL"></canvas></div>` width & height are set by css.

Comment: You need to check the image has loaded before you should attempt to render it. Also you have not provided the required information to solve your problem. `ctx.translate` and `ctx.rotate` are dependent on the current transform state. If you are scaling elsewhere that is the source of the problem. Try replacing `ctx.translate(x + width/2, y + height/2)` with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x + width/2, y + height/2)` , If that dont work then it must be the vars `width` and `height` that are at fault but you do not show where they come from

Comment: I replaced `.translate(...)` with `.setTransform(...)` but it has no affect, the problem stays the same. I will edit my post right now, to explain the source of `width` and `height`.

Comment: Also just uploaded some images of the rotation process!

Comment: Ok looks like you have inconsistent canvas size and canvas resolution. The `canvas.style.width` and `height` controls the size of the canvas on the page, and the `canvas.width` and `height` control the canvas resolution. If they do not match then you will get the stretching. Making them the same `canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px"` same for height will most likely fix the problem

Comment: You Sir save my day. Thanks alot, this really fixed the problem for me! I'd like you to post your comment as an answer so I can set the question answered and you get the reputation you deserve!

Comment: Good to hear. No point answering as this same question has been asked and solved many times, adding another answer will just make more clutter.